# How do I switch users or log off from Windows 8? It's not under the shut down menu

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

In every previous version of Windows, the "log off" option was in the same menu as the power options. In Windows 8, when I click the "power" button in the charms bar, there's no option to log off -- just sleep, shut down, and restart. How the heck do I log off or switch users in Windows 8?

So far I've just been typing `shutdown -l` from the command line, or pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to go to the lock screen, and switching users from there. I'm sure there's a better way, but I can't seem to find it!

[image: Sleep... Shut down... Restart... no log out?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that in Windows 8, the user switching and logout functionality has been moved to the top of the start screen. It's hard to tell that it's actually a menu button, but if you click your username on the start screen, a drop-down box will appear with options to log out, lock the screen, change your account picture, or choose a user to switch to.

[image: windows 8 logout screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can also add `shutdown, restart, log off, switch user` to the desktop right click(context menu) menu. Just [download this registry file](http://media.askvg.com/downloads/2012/03/Add-Cascading-Power-Menu-in-Desktop-Context-Menu.zip) and run the `add-menu.reg` file and it immediate add the menu to the right click menu. If you don't like it to keep their then simply run the `remove-menu.reg` file and it will gone form there.

[image: right click menu with power menu]

Information from this [source](http://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menu-for-restart-shut-down-hibernate-and-other-power-shortcuts-in-desktop-context-menu-of-windows-7-and-8/).

Comment: Just tried this on two Win8 installs - works great.

Comment: actually, i found a problem with this hack - the sleep command does not work correctly. it puts the computer into hibernation instead of sleep

Comment: @merk there could be a problem in registry entry of sleep, just compare it with hibernation key, as I don't have Win8 now for check it so I can't tell you exactly.

Answer (score 1):

See here for lots of ways:
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2584-lock-log-off-restart-shut-down-switch-user-windows-8-a.html

---

> While in the Start screen, click/tap on either your user name or picture tile to select the Lock, Sign out (Log off), or switch user option.

---

> Press the CTRL+ALT+DEL keys. From here you can select to Lock this PC, Switch user, Sign out (Log off), or you could click/tap on the power button at the bottom right corner to select to Sleep, Hibernate, Shut down or Restart Windows 8.

---

> While on the Desktop (Windows+D), press the ALT+F4 keys. From here, you can select to Switch user, Sign out (Log off), Sleep, Hibernate, Shut down, or Restart Windows 8.

---

> 1. Open the Charms Bar in Windows 8, and click/tap on Settings.
> 2. Click/tap on the Power button at the bottom right corner in the Settings slide out menu. From here, you can select to Sleep, Hibernate, Shut down or Restart Windows 8.

---

> Click/tap on the Power button at the bottom right corner in the Settings slide out menu. From here, you can select to Sleep, Hibernate, Shut down or Restart Windows 8.

---

> 1. Open Task Manager, and click/tap on More details.
> 2. Click/tap on the Users tab. From here, you can select a signed in user to Sign out or Switch user. (see screenshot below)

Comment: Would you mind taking some new screenshots? It's not preferable to copy a whole article verbatim, including watermarked screenshots. Summarizing the main points or rewriting them in your own style is great, but straight-up copypasta is not preferred.

Comment: Thanks. Not trying to be picky, I just don't want us to get in trouble over here, and it's always nice to get fresh screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

open run tiype "shutdown -s -t 0" press enter for shutdown
tiype "shutdown -r -t 0" for restart
tiype "logoff" for logoff
tiype "rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState" for sleep
tiype  "rundll32.exe User32.dll,LockWorkStation" for Lock Screen