# Switching quickly between users in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, users

I use an Administrator account and a user account and keep switching between the two often. Is there any keyboard / mouse shortcut to switch quickly between the two users? Much better if it doesn't prompt for password everytime!

Comment: If it didn't prompt you for the password, wouldn't that rather defeat the point of having separate accounts?

Comment: Not if it's being used for test purposes

Comment: Well, FWIW, you can switch quickly by using the [user drop-down menu  on the start screen](http://superuser.com/a/491480/20088). But there's no way to disable asking for the password to switch users, unless you don't have a password on the account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just login to your regular account and whenever you need to do admin stuff, just use `runas` command line. This should give you the best of both world.

Comment: you dont need to use the command line you can just right click on the exe.

Comment: @TaylorGibb, correct but `runas` with `savecred` option saves your credential to use for next time. over time, that'll save you time.

Comment: i would hate to have to open a runbox/cmd prompt everytime i want to run a program. The only way i could see this working is by using batch files, maybe.

Answer (score 3):

You can switch user (ie. Lock) by using the shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

If it does not prompt you for the password, it means there is no password (ie. it is disabled). Based on [How to remove login password from windows 8 logon and login automatically without entering it](http://xtendedview.com/computer/windows-8/how-to-set-auto-login-in-windows-8/645/), you should:

1. Run (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) `netplwiz`
2. Un-check the requirement to enter username and password.

   [image]
3. Remove any passwords set.

---

Alternatively, you can run as another user:

```
runas /savecred /user:domain\user "notepad"
```

If you do not know what domain and user is correct, you can ask `whoami`:

```
> whoami
domain\user
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of defeats the point, why dont you just run your programs as administrator from the other account.

This is a best practice anyway and is the sole purpose of UAC.

If you want to launch Metro apps as another user there is a Group Policy setting you can enable.